# looking to query a table based on count of items in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where I store a string which basically tells me the name of a document that I've saved for a particular client. So the table might looks like this...

```
ClientID      DocName
1234          1234_ContractAgreement_20150602_1248.pdf
1234          1234_ContractAgreement_20150601_1110.pdf
1234          1234_ContractLease_20150601_0939.pdf
```

So In this table I'm able to have multiple instances of the same client ID, as shown --1234. Depending on what they are doing, the system will generate a document and save it as .pdf. It will also save the document name in this table.

I'm looking to find Clients that have more than 1 type of DocName...specificall the `ContractAgreement`. The problem is each document has a timestamp at the end of it which differs based on when it was generated...

> _20150602_1248

For my desired result I'm hoping to only be able to see clients in this table that have more than one %ContractAgreement

Based of the table above, I'd like to get these results...

```
    ClientID      DocName
    1234          1234_ContractAgreement_20150602_1248.pdf
    1234          1234_ContractAgreement_20150601_1110.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` and `HAVING`

```
select *
from table
where clientID in(
    select clientID
    from table
    where DocName like '%ContractAgreement%'
    group by clientID
    having count(DocName) > 1)
```

Comment: Yah I noticed you had the group by and where in the wrong place........no worries.